# i cant get access to ssd

Tags: windows, ssd, format

i have ssd of sandisk 120GB one day it's just wouldn't access the windows (7 64bit)
now i'm trying to do whatever i know to format it in order of reinstall the os...
i tried to put the SSD on other computer and couldn't get access try to enter safe mode with/without command prompt with no success..
i put win 7 32bit on usb as portable and manage to get to load up the windows from the usb however when i open "Computer Management" -> "Storage" it wont load up..
next cmd "as administrator" -> "diskpart" -> "lis dis" -> "sel dis 0" (which is the problematic disk) -> "clean" ... it take few minutes then i get the message:

> Virtual Disk Service error:
>   Clean is not allowed on the disk containig the current boot, system, pagefile,
>   crashdump or hibernation volume.
>
> what can i do ?!

Comment: Things you should check for:
faulty cables,
faulty bios,
faulty firmware on your drive.
Things do do:
test other cables,
update your bios if possible,
update your firmware for your ssd.
Check on the manufactur sites on how it is done for your particulare system and drive.

Regards

Comment: Did you try booting linux live session and format drive from linux?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clean try format command.

Also you can try DBAN or a similar application to wipe the drive.

http://www.dban.org/
This one is free and designed for automatic disk erasure. It doesn't work on RAIDs but luckily that's not your case.

One more thing to try if you want to restore the data: try using Ubuntu instead of Windows live CD to see if it sees the drive correctly. 
You can also mount the partition in the event Ubuntu detects it. Let me know if the disk becomes visible and I'll get the instructions on how to mount it.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Sorry, will expand my comment now.